# VSTS AppStore extension fails to publish IPA on TestFlight

Tags: continuous-integration, testflight, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am new to VSTS and trying to setup a CI/CD process for my Xcode project. I am able to generate an IPA on my build agent and I can see it artifacts too. Now to publish this IPA on TestFlight, I am using VSTS AppStore extension which fails always with below error:

> No IPA file found using pattern:
>   /Users/BuildAgent/Downloads/_work/13/s/**/*.ipa

Any clue why its failing, as **Publish Artifacts** succeeds and IPA is generated.

Also I can see two IPAs in my artifacts folder, one inside build.sym and other inside XCodeTaskExport.

Comment: What're tasks of you build and definitions? Could you share the detail log files on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the files are published to artifacts, you can publish/deploy to app store by using release:

1. Create a new [release definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/)
2. Link that build as release artifacts
3. Add App Store task
4. Specify `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.ipa` in Binary Path input box.
5. Other settings
6. Start/trigger release

Comment: does that make any difference using $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)? instead of DefaultWorkingDirectory?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error occurred because I had used the wrong provisioning profile for my release pipeline. Changing it to the right one solved the issue for me.